# Fancybox - More complex title under image

Tags: jquery, fancybox

In fancybox 2, How can I add a more detailed title below my image ... i would like to have a title and a short description, with possibly some links?

Comment: You may want to check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/9611664/1055987

Comment: JFK ... this is really useful and answers my question perfectly. I have used that technique of adding in a separate div and using on 'afterLoad' to push it into the title and it works great. Thank you for pointing me to the other reference!

Answer (score 0):

you can check the documentation of fancybox. [FancyBox examples](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#examples)

may be try like this, as taken it from documentaion

```
$.fancybox( {href : 'yourimage.jpg', title : 'TitileName'} );
```

Comment: Sorry for not being clearer. I have read the documentation but i need to be able to add styling and html to the title and the examples and documentation don't illustrate that. Is it ok to put html into the  title string ?

Comment: @user1104799 why not you give a try .  as i not used it.

Comment: Woops ... added a comment in the wrong place and can't see how to cancel it!