# Hovertext removal using fancybox2.0

Tags: jquery, fancybox

My friends involved with the website http://thetutuproject.com/ and as you can see there is markup displayed in the hover text. Now I've tried the fix using

script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        helpers: { title: false}
    });
});
```

link:

```
<a rel="group" class="fancybox" href="001.jpg" title="derp">
    <img src="images/thumbs/001.jpg" width="140"/>
</a>
```

divs:

```
<div id="fancyboxTitles" style="display: none;">
    <div>fancybox title one</div>
    <div>fancybox title two</div>
    <div>fancybox title three</div>
</div>
```

That JFK suggested

But I have had absolutely no success. It still displays the title in the fancybox popup as "derp" or whatever text is in the title portion of that link. Any help would be greatly appreciated. The only other way I can think to fix this is put each image in a separate web page, but that way I don't think you could scroll between them.

Thanks

Comment: question: the "tutu project" site is the one you want to fix? .. if so that site uses fancybox v1.3.x. I guess I suggested a workaround for fancybox v2.x here http://stackoverflow.com/a/9611664/1055987 so if you want to apply that solution with your code above, you should upgrade to fancybox v2.x

Comment: I feel stupid, I knew it was something simple. Thanks, new to the website how do i credit you for resolving the issue?

Comment: I posted my comment as an answer so you can mark it as the correct on. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the "tutu project" site is the one you want to fix? .. if so that site uses fancybox v1.3.4.

I guess I suggested a workaround for fancybox v2.x [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9611664/1055987) so if you want to apply that solution with your code above, you should upgrade to fancybox v2.x