# Wordpress Caption as Fancybox title

Tags: jquery, wordpress, fancybox, caption

We have a client that is using a wysiwyg editor to add multiple photos and different bits to a custom post type.

They are including a caption using the Wordpress Image caption functionality.

How would we be able to (efficiently) use Fancybox's `title` option to do this?

Here is the structure:

```
<div id="attachment_180" class="wp-caption">
    <a href="image.jpg" rel="performance">
        <img class="size-full" src="someimagethumb.jpg">
    </a>
    <p class="wp-caption-text">The Image Caption</p>
</div>
```

Comment: that would be very simple using fancybox v2.x (you would need to hard-code it into WordPress). here it is how http://stackoverflow.com/a/9611664/1055987

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might want something like this

```
$('div.wp-caption').each(function(){
    var caption = $(this).find('p.wp-caption-text').text();
    $(this).find('img').attr('title',caption);
    $(this).find('p.wp-caption-text').remove();    
});​
```

**Explanation:**

For each pic `div` (as there may be many on the page), do the following

1. capture the text from the caption as inserted
2. add the text to `title` attribute in the `img` element
3. remove the caption `p` element

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/ZVu9e/

Comment: I was hoping that I wouldn't have to use a performance suck like .find but I don't think there is any other way…

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using a hook in the `functions.php` file instead of JQuery:

```
function add_title_attachment_link($link, $id = null) {
    $id = intval( $id );
    $_post = get_post( $id );
    $post_title = esc_attr( $_post->post_excerpt );
    return str_replace('<a href', '<a title="'. $post_title .'" href', $link);
}
add_filter('wp_get_attachment_link', 'add_title_attachment_link', 10, 2);
```

This will return the caption from the attachment and add it to the `<a>` tag as a title for most JQuery lightbox plugins.

For example, in Fancybox:

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    helpers : {
        title : {
            type : 'over'
        }
    }
});
```

The caption will now appear in the lightbox.

Answer (score 0):

Grab it, then pass to fancybox.

```
var txt = $( '.wp-caption-text' ).text();
//do fancybox with txt passed to the title property
```