# Fancybox Title Attribute Not Working

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I am trying to use the title attribute to acknowledge participants in a fundraising effort. I have added the title tag inside the href, but it only displays in one way. The inside attribute does nothing. Also, the title positioning is off to the right in IE 9, looks fine in FF.

Here is the page http://ipga.com/communications/photos/2013/bfc/index.asp

My FancyBox call in the page looks like this:

```
$("a.grouped_elements").fancybox({
    padding: 0,
    openEffect  : 'elastic',
    openEasing : 'easeOutBack',
    openSpeed: 500,
    closeEffect : 'elastic',
    closeEasing : 'easeInBack',
    closeSpeed: 500,
    closeClick : true,
    titlePosition : 'inside'
});
```

Any ideas would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option `titlePosition` is for fancybox v1.3.4. For v2.x (the one you are using) use this format :

```
$("a.grouped_elements").fancybox({
    helpers : {
        title: {
            type: 'inside'
        }
    },
    // other API options here v2.x
});
```

Comment: Thanks JFK...could have sworn I tried that...now how can I stylize (eg. center the text, or change the color) of the title?

Comment: @MichaelSmith : try using a different element for the `title` (like in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/9611664/1055987) so you can style it as you would with any regular html element of your page