# FancyBox's title from sibling container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox

I am having a real simple/stupid problem and my lack of jQuery knowledge isn't helping.

In principle I have a galley with multiple pictures and want to use a sibling-`<div>`-block with some HTML markup as title with FancyBox. Here's a bare-bones fiddle of my problem:

HTML:

```
<div class="someClass">
  <a title="some title"
     class="fancybox"
     href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_b.jpg">
    <img src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_s.jpg"
         alt=""/>
  </a>
</div>

<div class="captionClass">
     this should be <br /> the <b>caption</b>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({

  'beforeLoad' : function() {
     this.title = $(this).siblings('.captionClass').html();
  }

 });
```

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: the .fancybox div is not a sibling of .captionClass div

Comment: this.title = $(this).parent().siblings('.captionClass');

Comment: @SamBattat thanks, that was pretty obvious! :) Unfortunately, though, it's still not working, but my gut says it has something to do with FancyBox as I haven’t witnessed a working `<p>`-title in my research so far…

Comment: maybe http://stackoverflow.com/a/9611664/1055987 (check also linked answers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the function to `afterLoad`

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    afterLoad: function () {
        this.title = $(this.element).parent().siblings('.captionClass').html()
    },
    helpers: {
        overlay: {
            css: {
                'background': 'rgba(58, 42, 45, 0.95)'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/6gvjsd9u/

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you! Although I need the HTML-markup I used .html() but it still works. Now I only gotta wrap my head around the CSS ;)

Comment: Yeah .html() should work too, I don't know why I said that :)