# How to pass dynamic content to Fancybox iFrame

Tags: javascript, fancybox

I have Fancybox V1 up and running.
I am looping over a query to pull the images, titles and meta data.
It's passing the title (which is embedded in the A tag) to the iFrame.
I have added the extra variable to the title but all of that data shows up when you hover over the thumbnail and i just want it to show in the iFrame.

Trying to find an alternative way to pass this additional variable into the iFrame without using the A tag's Title.

Fancy box call:

```
    $j("a.fancybox").fancybox({  afterLoad: function() {
    this.title = this.title;
},


helpers : {
    title: {
        type: 'inside'
    }


}


});
```

Current HTML/Coldfusion:

```
 <a href="#stImage.sourceImage#" title="#stImage.title# #stImage.metainfo#" 
  class="thumbnail fancybox" rel="gallery">
                  <div class="image-container" >
                      <img src="#stImage.StandardImage#" alt="#stImage.title#" 
class="img-rounded">
                   </div>
                   #stImage.title#


                </a>
```

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: The options in your code are for fancybox v2 and not v1 as you said you are using. Anyways, if you want to pass information to the iframe, just because the title shows up, then check http://stackoverflow.com/a/9611664/1055987 if that helps

Comment: That worked great, thank you so much for the magic bullet, JFK :-)